# My application is not rendering a simple <h1> Tag in react js

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, jsx

So i am making a UI in which i've taken the data of users from reqres api and then i've made it into a table with their avatars, i've made it up till here but the problem is i am not able to render a simple heading on my webpage, i want to write a simple 'USER LIST INFO' it isn't rendering.

So this is my App.js:-

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import './App.css';
import title from './title';
import ReactPaginate from 'react-paginate'
import axios from 'axios'



class App extends Component {

  constructor(props){
    super(props)
    this.state = {
      users:[],
      isLoading:false,
      isError:false,
    };
  }



  //async function get request

  async componentDidMount (){
    this.setState({isLoading:true})

    const response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")
    const sec_response = await fetch("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=2")

    if(response.ok){
      const fetchedData = await response.json()
      var userData = fetchedData.data
      this.setState({users:userData, isLoading:false})
     /* console.log(this.users) */

    if(sec_response.ok){
      const sec_fetchedData = await sec_response.json()
      var sec_userData = this.state.users.concat(sec_fetchedData.data)
      this.setState({users: sec_userData})
      console.log(this.users)
    }

 
    } else{
      this.setState({isError:true, isLoading:false})
    }    
  }





  renderTableRows = () => {
    return this.state.users.map(user => {
      return (
      <div className = "container">
          <tr key={user.id}>
            <div className= "avatar">
              <img src={user.avatar}/>
            </div>
            <td>{user.first_name}</td>
          </tr>
      </div>
        )
    })
  }


  render(){
    
    const {users, isLoading, isError} = this.state
    const element = <h1>USER LIST</h1>

    if(isLoading){
      return <div>Loading...</div>
    }


    if(isError){
      return <div>Error...</div>
    }

    console.log(users)
    return (
        <table>
            <thead>
              <tr>
                {/* {this.renderTableHeader()} */}
              </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
              <div className="rowsName">
                {this.renderTableRows()}
              </div>  
            </tbody>
        </table>
      )

    ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
  }
}

export default App
```

Comment: where is your `<h1>` tag?

Comment: You don't have a <h1> in your code

Answer (score 0):

```js
ReactDOM.render(
      element,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

is wrong you need to have App in there like so:

```js
ReactDOM.render(
      <App />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

and render your element in the App render method like so:

```js
return (
     <div>
       {element}
       ...
     </div>
      )
```

Answer (score 0):

1. Define your `h1` tag inside your `return` statement.
2. Remove the use of `ReactDOM.render` inside your App. In your case, there should be only one `ReactDOM.render` function call inside your whole App.

```
return (
 <div>
    <h1>USER LIST</h1>
    <table>
       </** other elements here **/>
    </table>
 </div>
)

export default App
```